# CRM 2016 On-premises Installation with no Internet connection

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an issue regarding CRM 2016 On-premises Installation with no Internet connection.

At the "Download and Install Required Components" page - The installation program somehow required internet connection for downloading the all components …

I do not have internet connection from the server and I have all Required Components in the "Redist" folder as part of the installation folder.

I have tried and succeeded install all Required Components from that folder and still the installation required the "Required Components" repeatedly …

I is it issue regarding the installation files?
Can I install the CRM with implicitly for no-internet connection? 
Is it something configurability?

Any help will be great

10X
ItzikBS

Comment: Are you getting the error message for all required components or for a specific one ?

Answer (score 0):

You **CAN** install Dynamics CRM **without** internet connection.

[See Procedure here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2012/07/23/how-to-install-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-without-an-internet-connection/)

If you still have a problem [This post on the CRM Community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/148286) may help.

This [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950421), althought related to CRM 4.0 may give you some hints.

Comment: I have installed dozens of CRM(4.0,2011,2013,2015,2016 ) deployments in-site on-premises with no internet network connection what so ever, and it's never happened before …
I familiar with the Redist folder -  It's part of the installation folder / and files and It's locate in the  root of the installation folder , so I didn't have to manually create it …|

The issue focus in the installation program itself that ignore the folder and ask (with message box alert) to download and installs after I hit the "Install" button